# Comparing a Hashmap with Array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, hashmap

I am new to Java Programming and Hashmaps and I have a problem that I need help with.

I have a Hashmap that stores a collection of objects:

```
private HashMap <String, Turtle> turtles = new HashMap<String, Turtle>();
```

I also have a collection of shapes which I have added to the Turtle class:

```
ArrayList<String> shapes = new ArrayList<String>();
```

What I am trying to do is find a way so that it adds the shape object with a specified name to the turtle object with a specified name by passing the parameters of `String turtleName` and `String shapeName`.

I do not know how to go about this with a ArrayList and a Hashmap.

Comment: There are no shape objects. The `ArrayList` contains `String`s.

Comment: If you don't know how to do it write sudo code here to explain what you want to do.

Comment: Please give an example of one of your "shape objects" (which seem to be just strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood your question, what you need to do is:

1. Getting the corresponding `Turtle` in the `Map` using the `turtleName` key
2. Getting the `List` for this `Turtle` and add the `shapeName` to the `List`

Which can be translated in Java code too:

```
public void addShapeNameToTurtle(String turtleName, String shapeName){
    turtles.get(turtleName).getList().add(shapeName);
}
```

where `getList()` returns the `shapes` associated with the current Turtle's instance.

A prefered way would be to add an `addShapeName` method to your `Turtle` class (which will add the `String` you pass in parameter to the `List`), then the call would be simplified to  `turtles.get(turtleName).addShapeName(shapeName);`

You will also have to check that the mapping exists in the map and that the List is not null when getting it.

Also you should read the Javadoc of both classes to have an overview of the availables methods for both classes:

- [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)
- [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Comment: Apologies for the late answer, but thank you for your help! This worked for what I was trying to achieve, sorry everyone about how vaguely I had put the question; in the future, I'll try and be more specific!